# Missed "instance configuration" step during SQL Server 2008 R2 installation

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I have strange problem with installation of SQL Server 2008 R2. I am trying to install on Windows 7 x64 OS and there should be step named "Instance configuration". It's missed in my setup, after installation SQL services exist in system but there is no instance of server. Image of SQL Server 2008 R2 I downloaded from MSDN. I tried with Enterprise and Developer version with same result. Has anyone similar problem? What could cause that? I looked for some solution in web, I tried to uninstall all SQL items from 'Add/Remove Programs' and to clear registry - doesn't help. I will be very grateful for any tips. 
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a number of strange issues with SQL Server 2008 including that.

In my case it was on Windows Server 2008 x64 where I had the issues but I guess it would be a similar thing.

In my case it depended on my user rights, if I logged on with my credentials even though I am part of the Administrators group I had a number of different issues.

When loggin in as the built in Administrator it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Launching installer as "Administrator" worked for me.